# Create a categorical column based on different binary columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data= [[0,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]], columns = ['A','B','C'])

    A   B   C
0   0   0   1
1   1   0   0
2   0   1   0
```

I want to create a new column where on each row appears the value of the previous column where there is a 1:

```
    A   B   C value
0   0   0   1   C
1   1   0   0   A
2   0   1   0   B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dot`:

```
df['value'] = df.values.dot(df.columns)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C value
0  0  0  1     C
1  1  0  0     A
2  0  1  0     B
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`pd.DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df['value'] = df.idxmax(1)

print(df)

   A  B  C value
0  0  0  1     C
1  1  0  0     A
2  0  1  0     B
```